# Team Foundation Server 2012 - books, papers, etc

Tags: tfs

Do you have any online resources or good books for learning `TFS 2012`? I was looking for something in the web, but there are only poor guides and videos that show only the easiest cases of usage.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [VS ALM Rangers on codeplex](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ALM Rangers Guides, hosted in codeplex site:

Branching Guide - http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com

Supporting Guidance - http://vsarguidance.codeplex.com

among others: Build Customization Guide, Lab management Guide, Test Tooling Guide, Assessment Guide

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I have found: [Microsoft Virtual Academy Exam For TFS](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/administering-visual-studio-tfs-2012-exam-496-jump-start#fbid=37aRMRSY7-0)